# WebCliente.DownloadData gives File Not Found when file is .odt

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using WebClient.DownloadData function to download files as bytearray from a URL. This works perfectly for all types I've tried, except, apparently, .odt files. Other types that work are png, pdf, txt, doc, docx, xlsx. ODT specifically gives me a File Not Found error.

Function is as straight forward as possible:

```
        public byte[] GetBytes(string url)
        {
           using (var client = new WebClient())
           {
               return client.DownloadData(url);
           }
        }
```

The function is executed from a View in project A, whereas the file is located in a local folder in project B. Don't know if this makes any difference, given that other file types work as intended.
Of course, the .odt file is indeed in the local folder of project B, in the exact path that is received by the function.

Any ideas? Is this a .odt or other LibreOffice types kind of issue? I'd appreciate any help/insight :)

Comment: The code you are showing is likely not throwing the exception you are getting

Comment: @TheGeneral It is where VS is getting the exception, breakpoints run fine until the call returns.

Answer (score 2):

You need add odt mime type to web server.in webconfig add following:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".odt" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".odt" mimeType="application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```

If you are using .net core add follwing to startup:

```
  var contentTypeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
            contentTypeProvider.Mappings[".odt"] = "pplication/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text";
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                ContentTypeProvider = contentTypeProvider
            });
```

Comment: Already had the first code (I'm not using .NET Core). That doesn't work unfortunately.